# The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided in Postman

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I am working with Amazon SP-API to access seller data. I am trying to call the Report API but continuously countered with the following error: "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details"

When I remove the required parameters from the body the error changes to: "Access to requested resource is denied."

Can anyone please guide what can possible issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are providing all required parameters in the correct format. I got this error when I left out a parameter in the Listings api GetListingsItem.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to access it ? Through postman ? Or Java app or ?